# How do I upgrade appium in my Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, appium, specflow

I am writing my tests in C# with Appium and specflow. I am using Visual studio as my IDE.
If I want to upgrade my appium to the latest version how do I do it?
All new Appium methods for FaceID authentication are available in Appium version V1.10.1
Want to know how do I upgrade to that version of Appium.
Usually we update all the softwares through Nuget packages but for Appium only thinhg I see is Appium.Webdriver with latest version being 3.0.0.2 and this doe not contain latest appium code.
Any help in guiding me is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use node.js command line for upgrade the appium you just need to install node.js then it contains node.js command line so you can install or upgrade the appium

https://www.edgewordstraining.co.uk/2017/07/05/install-appium-server-windows/**strong text**

Comment: How does it upgrade in my visual studio where I am actually writing the test code?

Comment: i think you will not able to upgrade the appium using VS

Comment: How do I do it?